# Deck in the game Set

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

In the card game Set, each card features a number of shapes, with four attributes:
There is only 1 card for each possible combination of attributes.
For more information about the game: go [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(card_game))

Questions:

1. Find the number of sets where all three cards are the same for exactly $0$ attributes.
2. Find the number of sets where all three cards are the same for exactly $1$ attribute.
3. Find the number of sets where all three cards are the same for exactly $2$ attribute.
4. Find the number of sets where all three cards are the same for exactly $3$ attribute.

Comment: I have two problems with your query: (1) I am confused by (for example) "Find the number of sets where all three cards are the same for exactly 1 attribute".  Could you please **clarify** (perhaps with an *example*) what you *intend* this question to ask? (2) re MathSE protocol, please also edit your query to include the work that you have already done vs these questions, and specific areas where you are unsure or stuck.

Comment: @user2661923: The question does in fact ask what the OP wanted to ask, but one does have to know a little more about the game than is contained in the question. For all practical purposes you can think of each card as being a $4$-tuple of members of $\{0,1,2\}$, and the second question asks how many sets of $3$ of these $4$-tuples agree in exactly one coordinate.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Very good point, thanks for stepping up.

Comment: @user2661923: You’re welcome. I only knew because the Math Club at the university from which I retired used to play the game occasionally.

Comment: **Please do not discuss this problem!** This is an active AoPS homework problem.  @In-finite: realize that homework may be challenging. If you wish to receive some help from the staff or other students, I encourage you to use the resources that the online classes provide, such as the Message Board. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Each possible set with $k$ attributes that are the same can be uniquely constructed as follows:

1. Select $k$ out of $4$ attributes that will be the same,
2. For each of these, select the common "value" (e.g. if shape is a common attribute, select the shape),
3. For each remaining attribute, assign each of the three available options to one of the cards.

---

For example, in the case where $k = 3$, each set can be constructed with the following procedure

1. We first select $3$ out of $4$ attributes that will be the same; there are $\binom 4k = \binom 43 = 4$ ways to do so
2. We then select one of $3$ possibilities for each of the $k = 3$ attributes. There are $3^k = 3^3 = 27$ ways to do so.
3. There is $4 - k = 1$ remaining attribute. We distribute the $3$ possible values for this attribute among the $3$ indistinguishible cards. There are $(3!)^{4 - k - 1} =1$ way of doing so.

Thus, we find that all together there are
$$
4 \times 27 = 108
$$
sets that can be constructed in which $3$ attributes are the same.

Comment: Thank you for the hint!

Comment: Could you solve one of the 4 so I can see how the problem goes?

Comment: @In-finite See my latest edit

Comment: Oh, I get it now! Thank you! But one minor thing: wouldn't it just be $4\cdot27$ without step 3?

Comment: @In-finite I see your point; you might be right

Comment: @In-finite You're right; fixed my answer

Comment: Thank you so much @Ben Grossmann for all the help! I can solve the rest by myself now :) Thank you